# $\operatorname{Isom}{(M)}$ has Lie-structure for M metrizable manifold

Tags: metric-spaces, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a smooth and metrizable manifold. Then $\operatorname{Isom}{(M)}$ can be given the structure of a Lie group, so that the action of $\operatorname{Isom}{(M)}$ on $M$ is still smooth.

I found that as a sidenote somewhere. I really would like to see a prove of the above. So if somebody happens to know an online (free accessible) source, please tell me.
I know $\operatorname{Isom}{(M)}$ is locally compact w.r.t. the compact-open topology. Is this also the topology of the Lie-Group?

Comment: Certainly this doesn't even come close to answering the question, but you should think about the fact that the Lie algebra will be $\Gamma(TM)$, the vector fields on $M$ (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 3):

How about [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968928), [this](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/autmor00.pdf) or [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.0948v1)?

Comment: @fk44: I should mention that those links were obtained by a very simple Google search (I certainly have no expertise in this field). It is always a good idea to do a thorough search *before* asking a question on this and similar sites.